# SFINAE using std::enable_if: type parameter vs non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, non-type-template-parameter

```cpp
template<bool F, typename = std::enable_if_t<F>>
auto func1() -> int { return 0; }
template<bool F, typename = std::enable_if_t<!F>>
auto func1() -> int { return 0; }

template<bool F, std::enable_if_t<F, int> = 0>
auto func2() -> int { return 0; }
template<bool F, std::enable_if_t<!F, int> = 0>
auto func2() -> int { return 0; }
```

Here are two sets of overloaded functions: `func1()` and `func2()`.
`func1()` uses type parameter for SFINAE and `func2()` uses non-type parameter for SFINAE.

When compiling these functions, `func1()` causes compilation error but `func2()` does not. Why does SFINAE work for `func2()` and fails for `func1()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the first case, a SFINAE failure remove only the default for a template parameter.

```
// in case F is true, you have 

template <bool F, typename = void>
int func1() { return 0; }

template <bool F, typename> // no more default  but still available
int func1() { return 0; }
```

So doesn't disable the function, and you have two definitions of the same function (a default value doesn't change a function signature) so, as pointed by Jarod42 (thanks), you have a violation of the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

In the second case you remove a template parameter, so you destroy the function, so no collision anymore.

```
template <bool F, int = 0>
int func2() { return 0; }

// template<bool F, ...>  // function removed
// int func2() { return 0; }
```

You can verify that, in the first case, also the "disabled" function is still available, with a test with a single function

```
template <bool F, typename = std::enable_if_t<F>>
int foo ()
 { return 0; }
```

and calling it with `true`, `false` and `false, void`.

```
foo<true>();  // compile: foo<true, void>() called
foo<false>();  // compilation error: no second template paramenter
foo<false, void>();  // compile: explicit second template parameter
```

Comment: @Jarod42 - Thanks. I've modified the answer trying to express is better.